# echo incrementing numbers into text files in a directory with conditions

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command

I have a directory with thousands of text files. I would like to insert 50 number ones into the first 50 text files and 50 number two's into the next 50 files and so on up to number the number 15 and then repeat from number one again after that.

I also would like to be able to specify via user input the starting number (between 1 and 15) and also the number of times the starting number will be repeated (only for the starting number, 50 should be constant for the subsequent numbers).

For example: I input "3" as the "starting number" and "43" as the "number of repetitions for the starting number 3" so that "3" will be inserted into the first 43 files in the directory and "4" into the next 50 files, "5" into the next 50 and so on up to 15 and then repeat from 1 until all text files are processed.

Basically,

```
"3" >> files 1 to 43
"4" >> files 44 to 93
"5" >> files 94 to 143
"6" >> files 144 to 193
...
"15" >> files 594 to 643
"1" >> files 644 to 693
"2" >> files 694 to 743
...
```

Comment: please share your code which you have tried so far ?

Comment: ^ That's just it, I don't have one. I'm new to DOS commands/Microsoft batch files. I can do it without the per-fifty files condition, which is looping through all files in the directory appending numbers 1 to infinite.

Comment: Then you should at least add that to the question; questions which are nothing but task requests are considered as off-topic on SO; you need to show your own research, otherwise the question is probably closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET "startnum=%1"
SET "repeats=%2"
IF NOT DEFINED repeats SET /a repeats=50
IF NOT DEFINED startnum SET /a startnum=1
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%targetdir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
  CALL :appendx >>"%targetdir%\%%a"
)
GOTO :EOF

:appendx
 ECHO %startnum%
 SET /a repeats-=1
 IF %repeats%==0 SET /a repeats=50&SET /a startnum=(startnum %% 15) + 1
GOTO :eof
```

Seems a strange thing to do, but here it is.

You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

I'd suggest you test it against a dummy test directory.

Comment: How can I do it if I want to start from, say, number 3 and I want this number appended into the first 43 files only, not 50? But the rest of the numbers (4-15 and back to 1 and so on) will be appended one number for  every succeeding 50 files as normal?

Comment: As you asked in your question, you'd need to supply those parameters, so you'd enter *thisbatchname* 3 43 - the numbers supplied are unchecked.

Comment: I just realized that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /A count50=50, number=1
set /P "number=Starting number [press Enter for 1]: "
set /P "count50=Number of times [press Enter for 50]: "
set /A count15=number-1, count50=50-count50

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   >> "%%a" call echo %%number%%
   set /A "count50+=1, count15=(count15+!(count50%%50))%%15, number=count15+1"
)
```

Comment: I think EnableDelayedExpansion won't work for me because the filenames have exclamation points in them.